# How to count the documents duplicated in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I tried to search how to count the documents duplicated in mongodb and i got this function, it return the documents duplicated.

```
db.job_crawler_models_jobs_crawlings.aggregate(
    { $group: { 
        _id: { field1: "$field1", field2: "$field2" },
        count: { $sum:  1 }
    }},
    { $match: {
        count: { $gt : 1 }
    }}
)
```

But i want to get the number of documents duplicated. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding another $group in the pipeline. Not sure this is exactly what you are looking for though.

```
db.job_crawler_models_jobs_crawlings.aggregate(
{ $group: { 
    _id: { field1: "$field1", field2: "$field2" },
    count: { $sum:  1 }
}},
{ $match: {
    count: { $gt : 1 }
}},
{ $group: { _id: null, duplicatedCounts: { $sum:1 } } }
)
```